# Get specific part class using jQuery, Javascript, PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to create a link that functions as a like button.

Currently I have my like link like this:

```
<a href='javascript:;' title='Like' onClick='like_add_$id'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up fa-1'></i> Like</a>
```

And my like.js file is like this:

```
function like_add(post_id) {
    $.post('ajax/like_add.php', {post_id: post_id}, function(data) {
        if (data == 'success') {
            like_get(post_id);
        } else {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}

function like_get(post_id) {
    $.post('ajax/like_get.php', {post_id: post_id}, function(data) {
        $('#post_like_'+post_id).text(data);
    });
}
```

The thing is, as most of you might have already noticed, the `post_id` variable in the like.js does not hold the actual `post_id`. The `post_id` is stored in a PHP variable called `$id` in the PHP file.

Now, my question is, how would I take that `$id` from my PHP page and send it to my like.js to store the value in the `post_id` variable?

Any ideas are much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is `like_add_$id` supposed to be?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen That is the function that runs whenever someone clicks the link. The function is stored in the like.js file.

Comment: No, it is not. Are you sure  you did not mean `like_add($id);`? Also, where does `$id` come from?

Comment: There were indeed some small errors in the code. Using the hidden input as suggested by AndrienXL I managed to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hidden inputs :

```
<input type="hidden" id="postid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

Then in your js :

```
var postid = $("#postid").val();
```

Also I don't think your onClick will work, it should look like this :

```
onClick="like_add(<?php echo $id; ?>)"
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I don't think it processes it correctly in the like.js file. EDIT: it did work. There were some errors in the code. Thanks!